# How to install Web Dynamic Module in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic, module, web

**How can I install Web Dynamic Module 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 or 2.5?**

The version I have installed is 3.0.

I am trying to add Axis2 to my java project (in project Facets) and I am getting error that
Web Dynamic Module 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 or 2.5 is required.

I can't find any instructions on how to install this.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Never mind, there is little dropdown next to Dynamic Web Module 3.0 in Project Facets that allows me to change version to different one...

Comment: Uh. I've figured it. See UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

click right click on project -> properties -> project facets -> click on link then change dynamic web module part as your requirement.

[image]